# Inserting an icon to the right of the page title in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs, youtube

I recently noticed that when viewing YouTube videos in Chrome, it inserts a fancy looking audio icon into the tab when the video is playing. However the icon is not part of the actual page title, but instead appears to the right of the page title, like this:

[image: Youtube play icon]

Notice how the actual page title is truncated due to the tab length and fades out on the right hand side.

How is this accomplished? Is there an HTML or JavaScript property that can insert this icon there? What other icons, if any, can be used?

---

Note, I realize this is not cross-browser property since it doesn't work for FireFox. I'm wondering only about Chrome/Chromium.

Comment: As far as I can tell it works in FireFox and IE just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome added the icon to any tab making sound.  The idea is that when an Ad or music begins randomly playing, it needs to be easy to find and kill.

There is no HTML, JS, etc. that adds the icons. Anything that creates sound will place the sound icon on the tab in chrome -- while the tab is making sound.

The only similar icon I know of is the Chrome Cast icon, but that requires the Chrome Cast extension.

Comment: Shows on Grooveshark for me...  remember sound has to be playing.

Comment: Maybe there's some sort of a bug with the Chromium/Grooveshark/Linux combination.

Answer (score 3):

we don't need any script to do that. It's a feature developed by Chrome developer. Chrome will automatically display the icon when there is an audio or video playing.

More [info](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/01/everyone-can-now-track-down-noisy-tabs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does insert this icon, if I play video on other site, then it looks like

[image]